# I want to extract more than one paragraph to a csv file, but I want them in separate columns rather than in one big column

Tags: python, csv, xpath, scrapy

```
result = hxs.select('//*[@id="uobcms-content"]/div/div/p').extract() [1]
```

This extracts the second paragraph in that div, but I want all of them. I know that removing [1] extracts all the paragraphs but I want to extract them all into different columns. I've tried [1,2,3,4] and [1+2+3+4] to no avail.

Comment: How are you writing the result to a CSV? You already have a list, you'd use write the separate elements of that list as CSV columns.

Comment: scrapy crawl project -o project.csv -t csv. It's extracting paragraph 2 fine, but now I want paragraph 3 and 4 too, it puts all the scraped data into one column but I want the data in different columns so I can use the data after.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: That would write separate *rows*, not columns..

Comment: are you using `scrapy`'s `export_item`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
result = hxs.select('//*[@id="uobcms-content"]/div/div/p').extract() [1:]
```

it's called slicing.
It slices the list from the 1st element (0-based counting) to the end.

Comment: Yes this does retrieve more than one paragraph - great. But they are extracted in the same column, is there a way of extracting each paragraph to a separate column?